# Can’t resolve from IServiceProvider .net core

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I register some `masstransit` consumer in `IServiceCollection` but i can’t resolve from `IServiceProvider`.

Its my add consumer method.

```
 public static void Consumer(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
 {
      serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(x => { x.AddConsumer<BookCommandHandler>(); });
      serviceCollection.AddScoped<BookCommandHandler>();
      serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
 }
```

When i want to resolve give me not register error

```
  public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
  {
     var xx = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BookCommandHandler>();
  }
```

Where is my fault ?

Comment: Please post the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: btw, what is your intention in calling `serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();`? It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once registered you can access the object in the `ConfigureServices` method by passing it in as a parameter

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration, BookCommandHandler bcHandler)
{
    // use the class
    // bcHandler.
}
```